# Creating Controller For EF Model With Child Models Using Template

Tags: entity-framework, model, controller, asp.net-mvc-4

My title might be confusing but here is my problem. I'm new to EF and MVC4 coming from ASP.net and Linq to Sql

So I created my code first Models and the DB looks great just like I'd have written it.

```
//namespace Article.Models

public class ArticleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dimension> Dimensions { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public double Comission { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Group> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int AdTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dimension Dimension { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Dimension
{
    public int DimensionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

After the database is created I add the connection string to the web configue.

As I try and make Controllers I can make them for Category and Group with Read/Write Actions and Views using EF template no problem.

But for Article model and Group model I get the same kind of error

[image: Trying to add the Advertisement model to a new Controller]

But I get the following Error everytime

[image: Could not load type from Assembly]

Is there something I am doing wrong or is it impossible to use the Read/Write template in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question and its answer. this might help. [stackoverflow.com/questions/7859611/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-publickeytoken-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859611/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-publickeytoken-null)