# Type is not resolved for member 'MyProject.ViewModel.UserIdentity,MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, server-error

I recently completed my project in ASP.NET MVC with jquery but just one issue not solved sometime in every page this error alternatively occurs.

[image]

It is not affecting my work or any functionality but not good to show to the end user.

Is anyone got or get this type of error.

any answer to solve this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859611/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-publickeytoken-null

Comment: @pranavj thanks I will try