# Assembly Version was not found

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a solution that includes a server project and a client project.
The idea is to have the server send objects to the client, but whenever I try to send an object I get this exception on the client-side **System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException** saying that the assembly version was not found.

After reading this: [Could not load file or assembly, PublicKeyToken=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859611/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-publickeytoken-null), I thought I could fix my problem by having a shared Assembly Info file.

So I tried to follow this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects/, but the server project still seems to use the same assembly version as before I tried to make a shared one.

Any help would be appreciated whether it be with making a shared assembly or coming up with an entirely different solution.